# No data coming in from parsing JSON with Alamofire Swift 3 and Xcode 8 beta

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am trying to get data from an url in Swift 3 with Alamofire. There is no data coming through on the cell. I know I am messing something up somewhere but I am fairly new to swift 3 and cant see the issue, the code is below:

**JSON Structure.**

```
{
        posts:      [
             {
        id: “000000”,
        url: "/content/interview",
        date: "2016-11-03 09:01:41",
        modified: "2016-11-03 09:03:47",
        title: "An interview",
        summary:      {
        value: "<p>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text</p> ",
        format: "filtered_html"
        }
    ]   
}
```

**Swift:**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


var titles = [String]()

var mainURL = "https://www.testapi.com"

typealias JSONstandard = [String : AnyObject]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    callAlamo(url: mainURL)
}

func callAlamo(url : String){
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)


    })

}

func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONstandard

         print(readableJSON)
        if let post = readableJSON["posts"] as? JSONstandard {
            if let posts = post["posts"] {
                for i in 0..<posts.count {
                    let post = posts[i] as! JSONstandard

                    let title = post["title"] as! String
                    titles.append(title)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }

        }

    }


    catch {
        print(error)
    }


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return titles.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

The above bring no data into the "cell". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all  a JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`

```
typealias JSONstandard = [String : Any]
```

The author of the tutorial should name it `JSONdictionary` to make it clearer.

The value for `posts` is an array, JSON collection objects are very easy to identify:

- `[]` is array
- `{}` is dictionary

---

```
  ...
  if let posts = readableJSON["posts"] as? [JSONstandard] {
     for post in posts { // don't use ugly C-style loops 
        let title = post["title"] as! String
        titles.append(title)
     }
     self.tableView.reloadData() // reload the table view after the loop
  }
  ...
```

PS : In Swift (1-3) passing `.mutableContainers` is pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! I guess bringing in other data would be pretty much the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is here may be

```
     if let posts = post["posts"] {
                ---
            }
```

in previous line you get posts by readableJSON["posts"]. Post has no node named "posts".

try this code:

```
     if let allPost = readableJSON["posts"] {
             var posts = allPost as! NSArray
                for post in posts {
                    let title = post["title"] as! String
                    titles.append(title)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please never suggest `NSArray` in Swift in such a case

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITableViewDataSource` methode:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1 
}
```

Do not `reloadData()`too often:

```
func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONstandard

        print(readableJSON)
        if let post = readableJSON["posts"] as? JSONstandard {
            if let posts = post["posts"] {
                for i in 0..<posts.count {
                    let post = posts[i] as! JSONstandard
                    let title = post["title"] as! String
                    titles.append(title)               
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData() // moved out of loop
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

If the problem persists:

- Log: `titles.count`

Comment: The problem will persist